# Making an Exam in an Access Continuous Form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a problem that has left me stumped. I'm trying to create an exam consisting of 50 questions in an Access continuous form. Each question can be either multiple choice or true/false.  The issue I'm having a hard time figuring out is twofold:

1. How do I get the text box to display a question where the combo box will display the appropriate answer options to go with that question? (tblQuestions has an ID field along with the question and the tblAnswerOptions also has an ID field along with a Test_Question_ID

ie: ID = 1, Test_Question_ID = 1, Answer = Answer Option 1; ID = 2, Test_Question_ID = 1, Answer = Answer Option 2; ID = 3, Test_Question_ID = 1, Answer = Answer Option 3

2. How do I get Access to record the test taker's dropdown answer into tblStudentAnswers consisting of ID, Student_ID, Test_Question_ID, and Answer_ID?

I feel like there are a bunch of moving parts and I'm not sure where to begin to link them all together. Thanks for any help/advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar to this a while ago.  You can do it on a single form, with one textbox and an option group with how ever many answers you have for that question.  I created a couple of queries that randomly selected questions from a list of available questions, and then one at a time put the question on the form, and added the answers in a random order.  Once the student selected an answer and clicked Next, their answer was recorded and the next question and answers were put on the screen.

Obviously, this is specific to my setup and requirements, but this should give you an idea of how to move forward...

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, Ars As DAO.Recordset
Dim x As Integer, iMaxQuiz As Integer
Dim sSQL As String
Dim lQNum As Long

  'Check that student has questions
  If DCount("NTID", "qFoundQuestions") = 0 Then
    'No questions for student - Exit
    MsgBox "No questions have been found for you.  If you think this is in error, please contact your manager.", vbCritical, "No Quiz for you!"
    Quit
  End If

  'Check if user has already passed quiz...if so, exit
  If IsNull(DLookup("Passed", "tblQuizzes", "Student='" & Forms!fLoginDialog.NTID & "'")) Then
    'Student has not taken quiz
  Else
    'Quiz taken
    iMaxQuiz = DMax("QuizID", "tblQuizzes", "Student='" & Forms!fLoginDialog.NTID & "'")
    If Not (DLookup("Passed", "tblQuizzes", "QuizID=" & iMaxQuiz)) Then
      'Quiz not passed
    Else
      MsgBox "You have already passed the quiz for this round.  Congratulations!", vbInformation, "No need to retake."
      Quit
    End If
  End If

  'Create Quiz
  sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblQuizzes (Student, Taken, Passed) " & _
         "VALUES ('" & Forms!fLoginDialog.NTID & "', #" & Now & "#, 0)"
  DoCmd.SetWarnings False
  DoCmd.RunSQL sSQL
  DoCmd.SetWarnings True
  Quiz = dLast("QuizID", "tblQuizzes", "Student ='" & Forms!fLoginDialog.NTID & "'")
  'Save to local Temp Table - lttSelectedQuestions
  DoCmd.SetWarnings False
  DoCmd.OpenQuery "mtqRandomQuestions", acViewNormal
  DoCmd.SetWarnings True

  'Set Row Numbers
  RandToRow "lttSelectedQuestions"

  Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("lttSelectedQuestions")

  'Initiate Quiz
  QNum.Caption = QNum.Caption & 1

  'Set first Q
  Question = 1
  QuestionBody.Caption = rs!QuestionBody

  'Check if TRUE/FALSE question first
  If rs!MC2 <> "" Then
    'Not T/F - Randomly select answer order
    Answers 1
  Else
    'T/F - Set True as the first option and then assign which one is correct
    TFAnswers 1
  End If

  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
Private Sub TFAnswers(ByVal iQ As Integer)
Dim Ars As DAO.Recordset

  'Delete lttAnswers
  DoCmd.SetWarnings False
  DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM lttAnswers"
  DoCmd.SetWarnings True

  Set Ars = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("lttAnswers")
  Ars.AddNew
  Ars!AID = 1
  Ars!AnswerText = "TRUE"
  If DLookup("Answer", "lttSelectedQuestions", "Row = " & iQ) = "TRUE" Then
    Ars!Correct = True
  Else
    Ars!Correct = False
  End If
  Ars.Update

  Ars.AddNew
  Ars!AID = 2
  Ars!AnswerText = "FALSE"
  If DLookup("Answer", "lttSelectedQuestions", "Row = " & iQ) = "TRUE" Then
    Ars!Correct = False
  Else
    Ars!Correct = True
  End If
  Ars.Update

  'Insert into lttRandonAnswers
  DoCmd.SetWarnings False
  DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM lttRandomAnswers"
  DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO lttRandomAnswers (Row, AID, AnswerText, Correct) VALUES (1, 1,'TRUE'," & DLookup("Correct", "lttAnswers", "AID=1") & ")"
  DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO lttRandomAnswers (Row, AID, AnswerText, Correct) VALUES (2, 2,'FALSE'," & DLookup("Correct", "lttAnswers", "AID=2") & ")"
  DoCmd.SetWarnings True

  'Assign OptionLabel.Captions
  OptionLabel1.Caption = "TRUE"
  OptionLabel2.Caption = "FALSE"
  Option3.Visible = False
  OptionLabel3.Caption = ""
  Option4.Visible = False
  OptionLabel4.Caption = ""

  Ars.Close
  Set Ars = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub Answers(ByVal iQ As Integer)
Dim Ars As DAO.Recordset

  'Delete lttAnswers
  DoCmd.SetWarnings False
  DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM lttAnswers"
  DoCmd.SetWarnings True

  Set Ars = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("lttAnswers")
  Ars.AddNew
  Ars!AID = 1
  Ars!AnswerText = DLookup("Answer", "lttSelectedQuestions", "Row = " & iQ)
  Ars!Correct = True
  Ars.Update

  Ars.AddNew
  Ars!AID = 2
  Ars!AnswerText = DLookup("MC1", "lttSelectedQuestions", "Row = " & iQ)
  Ars!Correct = False
  Ars.Update

  Ars.AddNew
  Ars!AID = 3
  Ars!AnswerText = DLookup("MC2", "lttSelectedQuestions", "Row = " & iQ)
  Ars!Correct = False
  Ars.Update

  Ars.AddNew
  Ars!AID = 4
  Ars!AnswerText = DLookup("MC3", "lttSelectedQuestions", "Row = " & iQ)
  Ars!Correct = False
  Ars.Update

  'Run qRandomAnswers
  DoCmd.SetWarnings False
  DoCmd.OpenQuery "mtqRandomAnswers", acViewNormal
  DoCmd.SetWarnings True
  RandToRow "lttRandomAnswers"

  OTACheck

  'Assign OptionLabel.Captions
  OptionLabel1.Caption = DLookup("AnswerText", "lttRandomAnswers", "Row = 1")
  OptionLabel2.Caption = DLookup("AnswerText", "lttRandomAnswers", "Row = 2")
  OptionLabel3.Caption = DLookup("AnswerText", "lttRandomAnswers", "Row = 3")
  OptionLabel4.Caption = DLookup("AnswerText", "lttRandomAnswers", "Row = 4")

  If Not Option3.Visible Then
    Option3.Visible = True
    OptionLabel3.Visible = True
    Option4.Visible = True
    OptionLabel4.Visible = True
  End If

  Ars.Close
  Set Ars = Nothing

End Sub

'Check if there is an All of the Above or None of the Above answer...and place it as option 4
Private Sub OTACheck()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim iAID As Integer
Dim sText As String
Dim bAns As Boolean

  Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("lttRandomAnswers")

  Do Until rs.EOF
    If Right(Trim(rs!AnswerText), 12) = "of the above" And rs!Row <> 4 Then
      'Save to temp
      iAID = rs!AID
      sText = rs!AnswerText
      bAns = rs!Correct
      'Move last answer to this position
      rs.Edit
      rs!AID = DLookup("AID", "lttRandomAnswers", "Row = 4")
      rs!AnswerText = DLookup("AnswerText", "lttRandomAnswers", "Row = 4")
      rs!Correct = DLookup("Correct", "lttRandomAnswers", "Row = 4")
      rs.Update
      'Move Temp to last answer
      rs.MoveLast
      rs.Edit
      rs!AID = iAID
      rs!AnswerText = sText
      rs!Correct = bAns
      rs.Update
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
  Loop

  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Then, when the student hits the button to move to the next question...

```
Private Sub bNextQ_Click()
Dim iQNum As Integer
Dim sSQL As String

  'Check that an answer has been selected
  If OGAnswers > 0 Then
    'Save Answer
    sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblQuizAnswers (Quiz, Question, SelectedAnswer, Correct) " & _
           "VALUES (" & Quiz & ", " & Question & ", " & OGAnswers & ", " & DLookup("Correct", "lttRandomAnswers", "Row=" & OGAnswers) & ")"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL sSQL
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
  Else
    MsgBox "Please pick an answer.", vbCritical, "Answer missing"
    Exit Sub
  End If

  'Get next question
 '*****************************
  'Last Question?
  If IsNull(DLookup("QuestionBody", "lttSelectedQuestions", "Row = " & Question + 1)) Then
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Name, acSaveNo
    DoCmd.OpenForm "fResults", acNormal, , , , acWindowNormal
    Exit Sub
  End If
'*****************************
  Question = Question + 1
  QuestionBody.Caption = DLookup("QuestionBody", "lttSelectedQuestions", "Row = " & Question)

  'Prep form
  QNum.Caption = "Question #" & Question
  OGAnswers.DefaultValue = 0
  If DLookup("MC2", "lttSelectedQuestions", "Row = " & Question) <> "" Then
    'Not T/F - Randomly select answer order
    Answers Question
  Else
    'T/F - Set True as the first option and then assign which one is correct
    TFAnswers Question
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This will work on a single form, but on a continuous form...?

Comment: Awesome that'd be great, thanks! @Andre I honestly don't really need it to be a continuous form, I just figured it would be easier that way? but always open to other suggestions

Comment: No need for a continuous form, as long as it's ok to have only 1 question available at a time.

Comment: Wow ok this suddenly got a lot more complicated than I had anticipated lol I'll look through this and see what sense I can make of it. Thanks!

Comment: Lol, yeah...I tried to address a lot of issues in there, some of which you may not need to deal with.  At least, that should get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard the expression, "You can't get there from here."?

Your question assumes that you would have the answer combobox in the same form as the question.  What you'll need to do is actually have 3 separate forms.  The main form that will be the "test", a subform that will display the questions - it can be a multiple items form, so the user can scroll through questions, and a 3rd form - the answers form, where the user will select their answer.

Both the question form and the answer form will have to be subforms of the test form if you want to be able to display all the questions at once for the user to scroll through, so you'll have to write some vba code to update the answer form each time the question form is changed using the question form's "on current" event.

You can include a submit cmdbutton on the answer form that will check for a value in their answer and submit the value to the table.

The reason you need to have 3 different forms is that your rowsource for your answers combobox is constantly updating with different answers for each question and when you update the rowsource of the combobox on the form in which the question is asked, you're updating every combobox on every question in the multiple items form to the answers to just this one question.

[Preliminary setup idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHLuk.jpg)

Comment: Hmm and here I thought I would just be able to write a query and have the form run off of that query... I'll see what I can conjure up with your subform suggestions though and see what comes of it. Thanks!

Comment: No matter what you do on the multiple items form, when the combobox's rowsource is updated, answers already provided will visually change or disappear regardless of querying skills.  I added a visual representation of what I was talking about.  If they're all bound forms, you should make the main form and question form Recordset Type's snapshot, and only the Answer form's Recordset Type Dynaset.  If you've used Link Master Fields and Link Child Fields correctly and you're using bound forms, you shouldn't need the submit answer button on the answer form...

Comment: And as Rdster said, if you're willing to forego using the continuous form for the questions, and only allow the test-taker to view one question at a time, you can get back down to 1 or 2 forms.

Comment: Yeah it seems it might be easier to not do the continuous form and instead just do the single form with one question at a time.

Comment: If you change you mind, just so you know, the 3 form method can be done with virtually no VBA coding and you just turn off the boundaries of the forms and no one can even tell that you have 3 forms going.